# showing a successful alert message after sending an email

Tags: javascript

This is an email sending code

```
mail($ToID,$subject,$urltoemail,$headers);
```

after sending, the user is redirected

```
header("Location:".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

I have to show an alert of "mail has been send successfully" in the redirected page. How can I?

---

Excerpt of code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])) {
  $flag=true; $error="";
  /*Getting Values**********************/
  $ToID=$_POST['ToID'];
  $fromID=$_POST['fromID'];
  $subject=$_POST['subject'];
  $URL=$_POST['URL'];
  $message=$_POST['message'];
  /*Validating the data*****************/
  if(strlen($ToID)==0) {
    $flag=false;
    $error.="Enter To email address field";
  } elseif(!preg_match_all("|^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$|U", $ToID, $arr)) {
  $flag=false; $error.="Invalid To email address";
  }

  if($flag) {
    $urltoemail = "<html><head><title>Forgot Password</title></head><body> <table><tr><td>".$message."</td></tr><tr><td><a href='{$URL}'>Click here for viewing map</a></td></tr></table></body></html>";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    if(strlen($fromID)==0)
        $fromID = 'info@cimaps.co.uk';
    $headers .= 'From: '.$fromID. "\r\n";
    mail($ToID,$subject,$urltoemail,$headers);
    //$_SESSION['m'] = "item successfully deleted";
    header("Location:".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try include a variable in the redirected URL, triggering an alert on the page. Use

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']. "?sent=1");
```

and then include this somewhere:

```
if ($_GET["sent"]) {
    echo '<script>alert("The email has been sent successfully.");</script>';
}
```

If you are willing to change the structure of your code a bit more you could

- redirect to a new page, which contains the alert code.
- just show the alert directly on the current page, without reloading with a redirect.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? It's hard to speak so generally.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submitbtn']))
{

 $flag=true;
 $error="";
 /*Getting Values**********************/
 $ToID=$_POST['ToID'];
 $fromID=$_POST['fromID'];
 $subject=$_POST['subject'];
 $URL=$_POST['URL'];
 $message=$_POST['message'];

 /*Validating the data*****************/
 if(strlen($ToID)==0)
 {
  $flag=false;
  $error.="Enter To email address field"; 
 }
 elseif(!preg_match_all("|^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$|U",$ToID,$arr))
 {
  $flag=false;
  $error.="Invalid To email address"; 
 }

Comment: Right now you are redirecting the user back to the same page. Why do you need the redirect? You may be able to remove it and just place the script directly.

Comment: Ok..but if write so..alert message shows in blank page.and then shows the redirected page

Comment: If you don't want to change the structure of your code, I have updated my post with something you could do. Another option would be to redirect to a new page, which shows the alert, or to just show the alert directly, without redirecting.

Comment: For future use, i wouls suggest a pastie or something to put the code in ;-)

Comment: @Ashita: please edit your original question, instead of providing code within comments.